# Disable onScreen keyboard to a particular EditText in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm using several techniques to disable onScreen keyboard to a particular EditText component  in a Android activity

I use this chunk of code but it doesn't work

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService);
imm.ToggleSoftInput(ShowFlags.Forced,HideSoftInputFlags.None);

editText.Click += delegate { 
     DialogPublicName.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
     imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(editPublicName.WindowToken,0);
};
```

How can I resolve my issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do many way but a single line of code satisfy my need

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.semester);

    //Disable onScreen Keyboard
    editText.setInputType(0);
```